# Javascript - remove no UTF-8 from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, utf-8

I've this two line:

```
<oggetto>Consulenza tecnica Arch. Rocco Beretta</oggetto>

<oggetto>Consulenza tecnica Arch. Rocco Beretta</oggetto>
```

First is **not regular** UTF-8
Second line is **regular** UTF-8
Try with Google Chrome.

Now, I do not understand what is the difference between the two lines.
Can I remove no UTF-8 char from first line?

Can you help me?
Carlo

Comment: Can you clarify the difference?

Comment: What is the content of the encoding attribute of your XML?

Comment: The content of the enconding is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Hi Alex, I not understand the different between the two lines. For me the lines is same bud for Chorme the first line is not UTF-8

Comment: @CarloCamusso — What makes you think something is different between them in the first place?

Comment: @Quentin - I add two line in file.xml and I load them in Google Chrome. The output of Chrome says that the first line in not UTF-8

Comment: How do you generate the XML? Maybe during the XML generation one or more non UTF-8 chars are written inside the string (they could be also non visible chars)

Comment: @CarloCamusso — It doesn't when I copy/paste the code from the question. Whatever your problem is, you left it behind when you put the code on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin - I try now with copy/past the code put on Stackoverflow and the problem is present

Comment: Possibly there is something weird about your editor then. Or you aren't pasting into a blank file.

Comment: @All - This is the XML: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74145437/test.xml
Can I remove no UTF-8 char from first line?

Comment: @CarloCamusso - it is better if you provide test.xml with only the first line. This way we can see the error opening the file with Chrome. If I open the current text.xml file, obviously the browser complains because there isn't a single document root. When i save test.xml and remove the second line I can open test.xml in Chrome without problem

Comment: @Amedeo, retry. Now root tag is present.
First tag 'oggetto' in not UTF-8
Second tag 'oggetto' is UTF-8

But I not see difference. Can I remove no UTF-8 char from first tag?

Comment: @CarloCamusso ok, now I can see the difference. You have the hex character '03' inside your first tag wich is a control character. 
You can check it saving your file and opening it with an hex viewer like this one 'http://webhex.net/view/47e4472bee7ecb35e53db557f05b4cb5'.

Anyway, can you tell us how you generate and use this file? This way e can give you some hint on how to remove the character.